# Ошибка "несоответствие типов" Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Не пойму как исправить и почему так происходит следующую ошибку:

> Type mismatch. Required: TestList Found: String

В отдельном классе лежит класс данных ***TestList*** с одним параметром **name** строкового массива

```
data class TestList (val names: ArrayList<String>)
```

Далее в MainActivity я создаю **recList** список из  **TestList**

```
val recList = ArrayList<TestList>()
```

Далее мне нужно заполнить этот массив строковыми данными:

```
for((key) in data.legends.all){
     recList.add(key)
}
```

Ну и собственно в этом месте я получаю данную ошибку, почему так происходит ? Как это исправить ?

Comment: Очевидно вместо `key` следует передавать `ArrayList<String>` с этой строкой.

Comment: @user7860670 но мне нужны данные из ```key``` именно в ```TestList.name```

Comment: @user7860670 если я правильно понял ваш ответ, то мне нужно сперва наполнить строковый массив, а потом этот массив передать в TestList ?

Comment: Очень запутанно. Почему список назван `name`, а не `names`? Вы пишете "присваиваю этот самый TestList", а на самом деле приводите код, где вы создаете `recList` — список из `TestList`. То есть фактически у вас список из списков `names`, двумерный список. Конечно, в такой список нельзя положить строку `key`.

Comment: [Поправьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320235/edit) ваш вопрос, отразите явно ваши намерения, что вы пытаетесь сделать? Вам нужно что-то положить в двумерный список или вы где-то ошиблись и список на самом деле должен быть одномерным?

Comment: @Vadik список одномерный, мне нужно строки из ```key``` добавить в список ```TestList```

Comment: Похоже, вы хотели написать `val name: String`, а не `val name: ArrayList<String>`. Но тогда не очень неудачно выбрано имя для класса `TestList` -- это перестает быть "списком", а это элемент списка, назовите `TestItem`, например.

Comment: @Vadik Не удаляйте своё сообщение, это было полезно. Оформите как ответ, я закрою в вашу пользу, свой удалю ! Вы мне очень помогли и это малость того что я могу сделать

Comment: @Vadik Даже скопируйте мой текст, немного отформатировав. Огромное Вам спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен одномерный список, а вы создали двумерный. Итак, у вас есть класс, который содержит в себе изменяемый список имен `names`:

```kotlin
data class TestList(val names: MutableList<String>)
```

Чтобы создать экземпляр этого класса, нужно просто вызвать конструктор и передать туда пустой список:

```
val list = TestList(names = mutableListOf())
```

Далее, пополнить `names` можно следующим образом:

```kotlin
for((key) in data.legends.all){
    list.names.add(key)
}
```

**UPD:**

Выяснилось, что `TestList` на самом деле должен называться `TestItem` и содержать в себе `name`, а не `names`:

```kotlin
data class TestItem(val name: String)
```

Если вам непринципиально, чтобы реализация списка была именно ArrayList, то изменяемый список в Котлин лучше создавать таким образом:

```
val list = mutableListOf<TestItem>()
```

А в цикле просто создаем новый экземпляр `TestItem` и добавляем его в список:

```
for((key) in data.legends.all){
    list.add(TestItem(key))
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое